# Prettier - the meaning of parantheses around assigned variables

Tags: javascript, formatting, format, prettier

- VS Code 1.16

I format code with Prettier with formatting on save. I get weird parantheses around assigned variables;

I have these two variables

Before formatting:

```
   tlProjectLoader = new TimelineMax({
      paused: true
   }),

  $laoder = $(this).find('.loader');
```

After formatting:

```
  (tlProjectLoader = new TimelineMax({
    paused: true
  })),

  ($laoder = $(this).find('.loader'));
```

I know this is casued by Prettier, as when I turned it off and that behaviour does not occur. So, why? If I don't need it - how to turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it happens when you declare global variables in one statement (separated by commas, instead of semicolons)

So you have two options: either use `var`/`let`/`const`, or separate the declarations with semicolons:

```
global = 123;
anotherGlobal = 345;
```

Tip: you can test Prettier output on the [Prettier Playground](https://prettier.io/playground)

Comment: What about the third option of turning off that rule? Can't find it in docs though...

Comment: @Sebastian, I doubt that you can configure that.
Also I would recommend using const for global variables, and use let/var for locals. Avoid using global variables when you can.

Comment: If these are not declarations but assignments, I don't see any sense in leaving them in one statement. Separate them with a `;` instead of `,`, as I suggested in the answer.